# Jackson (de)serializing object as its id

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Categories implements Serializable {
    private int id;    
    private String name;

    private Categories parent;

    // ....    

}
```

I'd like to serialize it to following json:

```
{ id: 1, name: "some name", parent: 5 }
```

So, main challenge here is to represent parent object as its id. Same thing i want
for deserialization.

I scannned rather large Jackson wiki and did not found anything that allowed
to accomplish this without writing plethora of custom code.
I think this is pretty common task and solution shold be somewhere nearby.

Also it would be nice if solution will allow to customize null value cases.

**UPD:**

Now trying to use `XmlTypeAdapter` approch, not happy with it btw, because i need to write TypeAdapter
for everyy single type i have and all they going to contain almost the same code:

```
public class CategoriesTypeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Integer, Categories> {

    @Inject
    CategoriesFacade dao;

    @Override
    public Categories unmarshal(Integer v) throws Exception {
        return dao.find(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer marshal(Categories v) throws Exception {
        return v.getId();
    }
}
```

Change in Categories.java:

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CategoriesTypeAdapter.class)
    private Categories parent;
```

**UPD1:**

And this is also not worked for me, at least deserializing now always return null in place of object, no idea how to debug this :
For this JSON:

```
{ id: 1, name: "test", parent: 5 }
```

I get parent always null now:

```
Categories{categoryId=1, name="test", parentId=null}
```

**UPD2:**

I found that htere is my fail in tis isssue, just did not setup things propertly, and my web.xml was lacking this entry:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.neopod.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways that might work, depending on exact semantics.

First is to use annotation pair `@JsonManagedReference` / `@JsonBackReference`, where first is used on "forward" property, and second on "backward" reference. In those cases, second property is not included in serialization, but is recovered during deserialization. This works for simple hierarchic objects.

Second is `@JsonIdentityInfo` (added in 2.0), and it adds support for arbitrary object references, regardless of direction. It works by serialization each Object as-is the first time it is seen; but on later references serializing them as ids. Deserialization restores linkage automatically.

Comment: Is there any useage examples ? I tried both, but with no visible success. Fields still deserialized as object with all fields empty.
Especially interested in `PropertyGenerator` usage, i need to generate id based on `getId/setId` POJO property

Comment: Jackson 2.0.0 announcement (http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_466.html) has an example, but unit tests might be the best source. `PropertyGenerator` is the "Bring Your own Id" way.

Comment: One thing: there is no way to avoid serializing the _first instance_ of referred object fully the first time; this is required to deserialize things correctly.

Comment: i seen this blog entry erlaier, but there is example of IntSequenceGenerator, i decided that don't need it, because i have id already generated by database, so i put there PropertyGenerator and nothing seem changed about deserialization. Going to check tests, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use propery access to field `Categories`

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Categories implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement
    Integer categoryId;

    @XmlElement
    String name;

    Categories parentId;

    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getParentId()
    {
        return parentId == null ? null : parentId.getCategoryId();
    }
}
```

test

```
Categories c = new Categories();
c.categoryId = 1;
c.name = "name";
Categories c1 = new Categories();
c1.categoryId = 2;
c.parentId = c1;
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(c));
```

output

```
{"categoryId":1,"parentId":2,"name":"name"}
```

**EDIT:**
make two gatters.
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public class Categories implements Serializable {

```
    @XmlElement
    Integer categoryId;

    @XmlElement
    String name;

    Categories parentId;

    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }  
    public Category getParentId()
    {
        return parentId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "parentId")
    Integer getParentIdForJSON()
    {
        return parentId == null ? null : parentId.getCategoryId();
    }  

}
```

Comment: I think this is not what i need, i have getters and setters already   return/accept `Categories` object, not `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this also does not work for me